# How do I scroll a list created with input type radio?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

this is my code,
I want them to be activated when I scroll down or up,not by clicking them

```
<input type="radio" name="buttons" id="r1" checked>    
<input type="radio" name="buttons" id="r2">    
<input type="radio" name="buttons" id="r3">    
<input type="radio" name="buttons" id="r4">   

<div class="controls">
    <label for="r1"><span></span>LAB & Process Development</label>
    <label for="r2"><span></span>Quality & Regulatory</label>
    <label for="r3"><span></span>Engineering & Project Management</label>
    <label for="r4"><span></span>EHS</label>
</div>
```

thank you for helping me

Comment: Explain what you want to happen, and in response to what event(s); if we can't understand your question, we can't answer it. Please read the "*[ask]*" guidelines for advice on asking good questions, and also the "*[mcve]*" guidance to ensure you've posted enough code to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't truly understand what you want to achieve.

However, if you want to do anything on scroll, you should listen to the scroll event.
You have two choices:

1. you can check when the user scrolls taking the mouse on the radio
2. you can check when the user scrolls anytime

In first case:

```
document.getElementById('controls').addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    //activate your element
});
```

In second case:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    //activate your element
});
```

EDIT: as requested in the comment.
It depends how you want to achieve this. For example you could want to check each radio by looping them:

```
let current = 1;
let max = 4;

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    //you need to uncheck the current one first
    document.getElementById('r' + current).checked = false;
    //If you reach the last radio element you reset the counter
    if(current == max) 
        current = 1;
    else
        current += 1;

    //Finally you activate the next radio
    document.getElementById('r' + current).checked = true;
});
```

This is a very simple implementation that can be improved.

Comment: I want to implement the second one, but I don't know JavaScript. Can you tell me how to activate it?

Comment: @NaziA I added details in my answer. If you are satisfied and it solves your issue, please accept it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: thank you for your answer but It scrolls too fast i try to slow it down but it didn't work, can you slow it down please?

Comment: You need to add a counter outside of the listener: let amount = 0;
Inside the listener you increase the counter: amount++;
Then check if it reached a certain amount and, if yes, you perform your actions:
if(amount >= 500) {
    //your listener body here
    amount = 0; //don't forget to reset the counter
}

Comment: thank you very much for your previous help, but now I have a problem, when I scroll for example twice and then I want to scroll up, it scrolls down.  How can I solve it?